# How to add class on element from javascript with watcher property?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I need to add class on element when some data property changes. I am using watcher to check for value change and adding a class as shown below.

```
 <div class="ad-video" >
      
watch: {
  testAdActive() {
   document.querySelector('.ad-video').classList.add('ad-resize');
  }
}
```

But somehow above code is not working. This class ad-resize is not getting added.
Please suggest if needs to be done in some other way.

Thanks,
Jyoti

Comment: Please show the "watcher" code

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it with [class-binding](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax-2):

```
<div :class="{ 'ad-video': testAdActive }">

</div>
```

---

So when the variable `testAdActive` is true, your class `.ad-video` will be placed on your div-element.

the `:` stands for `v-bind`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.
Actually, when testAdActive changes, i need to check some condition inside watcher and then apply CSS accordingly. Is it possible?

Comment: sure - please ask a new question or share some information with us. What are the conditions? How should the result look like?